# samba : unstable access to shares - INVALID ARGUMENT

Tags: 14.04, samba

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, I'm having some problems with smb shares, they work fine but after some time, they get unacessible, the error thrown is **INVALID ARGUMENT**, any of you had this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll need to show us your samba shares

Comment: @LnxSlck Whats the best way to do so?

Comment: Do you have like a smb.conf file?

Comment: Same problem here, also Ubuntu 14.04. Google tell me it is a bug, but has been fixed. In another Ubuntu 14.04, I didn't face similar problem.